# How do you do inner joins and paging in NHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I'm relatively new to NHibernate, and I'm trying to do something that seems quite tricky...

I have a relationship as follows:

User <*----1> Company <1----*> Shop

What I want to get is a paged list of shops for a given user.
My method looks like this:

```
public PagedCollection<Shop> GetForUser(int userId, int page, int pageSize, string sortColumn, Enums.SortDirection sortDirection)
    {
        using (var session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
        {
            //.. Todo!
        }
    }
```

For completeness, the resulting paged collection object has the following properties:

```
public ICollection<T> Items { get; private set; }
public int PageNumber { get; private set; }
public int ItemsPerPage { get; private set; }
public int TotalItems { get; private set; }
```

I guess there are two questions here:

1) How can I get the total items, and list of items using the page/pagesize/sort constraints?

2) How can I do the required inner join to go from the user to the shop table?

I'm really keen on a fully typed answer, as opposed to sql strings if that is at all possible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While both answers by @BradLaney and @sJhonny were useful, I still needed to do some digging to come up with a working result. Since I can't tick both as correct, I decided to post my working code as an answer:

```
var queryOver = session.QueryOver<Shop>()
                        .JoinQueryOver(s => s.Company)
                        .JoinQueryOver<User>(c => c.Users)
                        .Where(u => u.Id == userId);

IEnumerable<T> list = queryOver
            .OrderBy(Projections.Property(sortColumn)).Asc
            .Take(itemsPerPage)
            .Skip(pageNumber * itemsPerPage)
            .Future();
if (sortDirection == ESortDirection.Descending) list = list.Reverse();
int totalCount = queryOver.ToRowCountQuery().FutureValue<int>().Value;

return new PagedCollection<T>(list.ToList(), pageNumber, itemsPerPage, totalCount);
```

<strike>I'm not that happy with the sort direction clause, but I'm not sure how else to do it with the fluent interface.</strike> (See below)

Also, I wrapped the paging stuff into an extension method similar to the one mentioned by @Jhonny.

**Edit:**
I added the following extension method to take care of the ordering:

```
public static IQueryOver<T, U> OrderBy<T, U>(this IQueryOver<T, U> queryOver, IProjection projection, ESortDirection sortDirection)
    {
        if (sortDirection == ESortDirection.Descending) return queryOver.OrderBy(projection).Desc;
        else return queryOver.OrderBy(projection).Asc;
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hey if you want to fix your sorting problem add this extension:
http://weblogs.asp.net/davidfowler/archive/2008/12/11/dynamic-sorting-with-linq.aspx or download and install the Dyanmic LINQ library: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Comment: this is also the solution I ended up with (including the SortDirection enum, which I find perfectly acceptable). I guess great minds think alike :). best of luck!

Comment: Thanks guys - I updated my answer with a sorting extension method that I came up with last night after going to bed. Great minds surely do think alike :D

Answer (score 2):

1. ToRowCountQuery(), Take(), Skip(), OrderBy(). see [here](http://rookian.com/wordpressBlog/index.php/2010/09/25/paging-with-nhibernate-3-0-using-the-new-query-api-queryover/)
2. JoinQueryOver() (see [here](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/12/17/queryover-in-nh-3-0.aspx))

Answer (score 1):

If you are using 3.0 you can use:

```
session.QueryOver<Entity1>()
.Where(x => x.Compare1 == 5)
.JoinQueryOver<Entity2>(x => x.Entity2)
.Where(x => x.Compare2 == 10)
.Skip(10)
.Take(5)
.List()
```